# AspectJ Pointcut to introspect a local method code and print a variable inside local method

Tags: aspectj, pointcuts

I am trying to write a pointcut and advice which could print a string from following method -

```
public CustomerDto getCustomer(Integer customerCode){           
           CustomerDto customerDto = new CustomerDto();           
           String emailID =getEmailAddress();
           customerDto.setEmailAddress(emailID);             
           customerDto.setEmployer(getEmployer());
           customerDto.setSpouseName(getSpouse());
           return customerDto;      
}
```

I am unable to figure out a way by which a pointcut look at String emailID and then print the value of the same in an advice.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do.  Are you trying to execute an advice whenever getCustomer is executed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you need something like the following:

```
public privileged aspect LocalMethodCallAspect {
    private pointcut localMethodExecution() : withincode(public CustomerDto TargetClass.getCustomer(Integer)) && 
        call(private String TargetClass.getEmailAddress());

    after() returning(String email) : localMethodExecution()
    {
        System.out.println(email);
    }
}
```

Where `TargetClass` is a class containing `getCustomer()` and `getEmailAddress()` methods.

Or the same using @AspectJ:

```
@Aspect
public class LocalMethodCallAnnotationDrivenAspect {
    @Pointcut("withincode(public CustomerDto TargetClass.getCustomer(Integer)) && " +
            "call(private String TargetClass.getEmailAddress())")
    private void localMethodExecution() {

    }

    @AfterReturning(pointcut="localMethodExecution()",returning="email")
    public void printingEmail(String email) {
        System.out.println(email);
    }
}
```

Comment: I know this is an old question, but I can't get the @AspectJ part to work.

When I use `withincode` I get the error `Pointcut expression 'localMethodExecution()' contains unsupported pointcut primitive 'withincode'`

When I try `@withincode` I get the error `Pointcut is not well-formed: expecting ')' at character position 19
@withincode(public int com.....`

I am using AspectJ annotations, though in the Spring documentation it says that _Spring_ does not support `withincode` and `@withincode`... is that the reason it won't work?

Comment: @Roger  Ask a new question.